# How does contain (in background-size) exactly works or why not working here?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to learn css. I have been following lots of tutorials and are now in the section where I learn about the values of background-size.

I have been making fiddles trying every value but I cannot seem to make it work with contain or with porcentages

Here is my fiddle with the value content: http://jsfiddle.net/r3h2p46r/

I have used the same code I have used for every other value:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://bit.ly/1Rq1kp3");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

I cannot make it work with percentages either: http://jsfiddle.net/p3btc7oc/

Any ideas why is this happening?

They seem to all work here: http://bit.ly/1Q6z643

But now when I try by myself

Thanks!

Comment: your body doesnt have any height, that's why no background is shown. Add some content inside body.

Answer (score 0):

background-size: contain;

It is not visible here because contain take the size of body and here your body tag is empty...

For more information...JUST CHECK IT--------->

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain